# NullPointerException applying a function to spark RDD that works on non-RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a function that I want to apply to a every row of a .csv file:

```
def convert(inString: Array[String]) : String = {

    val country  = inString(0)
    val sellerId = inString(1)
    val itemID   = inString(2)
    try{
     val minidf = sqlContext.read.json( sc.makeRDD(inString(3):: Nil) )
        .withColumn("country", lit(country))
        .withColumn("seller_id", lit(sellerId))
        .withColumn("item_id", lit(itemID))
         val finalString = minidf.toJSON.collect().mkString(",")
        finalString
    } catch{
         case e: Exception =>println("AN EXCEPTION "+inString.mkString(","))
         ("this is an exception "+e+"  "+inString.mkString(","))
    }
}
```

This function transforms an entry of the sort:

```
CA      112578240       132080411845    [{"id":"general_spam_policy","severity":"critical","timestamp":"2017-02-26T08:30:16Z"}]
```

Where I have 4 columns, the 4th being a json blob, into

```
[{"country":"CA", "seller":112578240", "product":112578240, "id":"general_spam_policy","severity":"critical","timestamp":"2017-02-26T08:30:16Z"}]
```

which is the json object where the first 3 columns have been inserted into the fourth.

Now, this works:

```
val conv_string = sc.textFile(path_to_file).map(_.split('\t')).collect().map(x => convert(x))
```

or this:

```
val conv_string = sc.textFile(path_to_file).map(_.split('\t')).take(10).map(x => convert(x))
```

but this does **not**

```
val conv_string = sc.textFile(path_to_file).map(_.split('\t')).map(x => convert(x))
```

The last one throw a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

I included a `try catch` clause so see where exactly is this failing and it's failing for every single row.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you cannot put `sqlContext` in a Spark map, since that object can only exist on the driver node.

Comment: I see. Any particular recommendation to parse the json object, insert new information, and write back to a json string?

Comment: spray-json is probably the best one to use: https://github.com/spray/spray-json

Comment: want to make your first comment an answer so that I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot put `sqlContext` or `sparkContext` in a Spark map, since that object can only exist on the driver node. Essentially they are in charge of distributing your tasks.

You could rewite the JSON parsing bit using one of these libraries in pure scala: https://manuel.bernhardt.io/2015/11/06/a-quick-tour-of-json-libraries-in-scala/